# The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries in iOS Project Objective C Language

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

## **Report**

**What did I do?**

I tried to run the **pod install** or **arch -x86_64 pod install** command

**What did you expect to happen?**

I want to pod install Facebook with **use framework!**.
Currently, I am using a static library.

**What happened instead?**

> [!] The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries:
>
> The Swift pod `FacebookCore` depends upon `FBSDKCoreKit`, which does not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.
>
> The Swift pod `FacebookLogin` depends upon `FBSDKCoreKit` and `FBSDKLoginKit`, which do not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.
>
> The Swift pod `FacebookShare` depends upon `FBSDKCoreKit` and `FBSDKShareKit`, which do not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.

[image]

**CocoaPods Environment**

```
CocoaPods : 1.15.1
```

[image]

**Podfile**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

def facebook_pods
#   pod 'Bolts'
#  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', :modular_headers => true
#  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FacebookLogin'
  pod 'FacebookShare'
end

def all_pods
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'StreamingKit', '0.1.29'
  pod 'TYMActivityIndicatorView'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManager','~> 6.0.1'
  pod 'iOS-Slide-Menu', '~> 1.5'
  pod 'TwitterKit'
  pod 'TwitterCore'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
  pod 'MBProgressHUD'
  pod 'UCZProgressView'
  pod 'BIZActivityButton'
  pod 'TagCellLayout'
  pod 'AnimatedCollectionViewLayout'
  pod 'CardsLayout'
  pod 'SegmentedProgressView'
  pod 'VIMediaCache'
  pod 'ZFTokenField'
  pod "CleverTap-iOS-SDK"
  pod 'SDWebImageFLPlugin'
  pod 'FlexiblePageControl'
  pod 'YoutubePlayer-in-WKWebView'
  pod 'PayUIndia-Custom-Browser'
  pod 'PayUIndia-PG-SDK'
#  pod 'lottie-ios'
#  pod 'PromiseKit'
  pod 'Adjust', '~> 4.29.2'
  pod 'Toast-Swift', '~> 5.0.1'
  pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 10.5.2', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Realm', '~> 10.5.2', :modular_headers => true

  facebook_pods
end



# Service Extension Use All Available pods

def serviceExtensionAllTargetPods
#  pod "CleverTap-iOS-SDK"
end



target 'MyApp' do
  all_pods
end

target 'MyApp Development Stage' do
  all_pods
end

target 'MyApp Development Stage Simulator' do
  all_pods
end

target 'MyApp Development Live' do
  all_pods
end

target 'MyApp Development Live Simulator' do
  all_pods
end

target 'MyApp Enterprise Stage' do
  all_pods
end

target 'MyApp Enterprise Live' do
  all_pods
end

target 'ServiceExtension' do
  serviceExtensionAllTargetPods
end

target 'MyApp ServiceExtension' do
  serviceExtensionAllTargetPods
end

target 'MyApp Enterprise ServiceExtension' do
  serviceExtensionAllTargetPods
end
```

I want to pod install Facebook without **use framework!**.

Currently, I am using a static library.

And I don't want use `use_modular_headers!` globally.

Comment: I can't help with the question itself, but FYI macOS lets you take screenshots of individual windows. It makes them perfectly cropped, without needing to spend the effort to crop a full-screen screenshot yourself. See "How to capture a window or menu " on https://support.apple.com/en-us/102646

Comment: I think you need to `import FacebookCore` before you import the other 2 pods

Comment: @timbretimbre The first thing is when you remove **use framework!** in Podfile pod can't install. Specifically **pod 'FacebookShare'**

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. You should edit your question and replace the pictures with the actual text, copied and pasted. Text in pictures can't be searched or referenced and the text is much harder to read. It's also more work to post.

Comment: @Alexander
Its macOS sonoma 14.1.1.
when I remove podfile **use framework!** in the demo project pod install giving me an error.

>you may set use_modular_headers! globally in your Podfile, or specify :modular_headers => true for particular dependencies.

If I use **use_modular_headers!** then not issue mut my other pods change and **FacebookShare** pod not working **:modular_headers => true**.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is you need to have `pod FacebookCore` before the other 2 pods. See: https://cocoapods.org/pods/FacebookCore